# I am trying to use jquery to use a slide toggle on a website

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to click an image and have a div come out of the TOP of the image. I have seen examples of how to make it come out of the bottom just not the top.

Here is an example of it coming from the bottom:

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_slide_toggle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just change the order:

```
<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>
<div id="flip">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you got you right, you want `panel` to come out of top of `flip`? Why won't you switch places of those two divs:

```
<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>
<div id="flip">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I am new to this so that was probably a pretty stupid question. Thanks again